# Sails js subscribe to model changes scoped by groupid attribute

Tags: javascript, socket.io, sails.js, publish-subscribe

I have a model named Groupfeed which looks like this

```
module.exports = {

  schema:true,
  attributes: 
  {
    groupid:
    {
        model:'groups',
        required:true
    },

    postid: 
    {
        model:'post',
        required:true
    },

    objectid: 
    {
        model:'objects',
        required:true
    },
  }
};
```

On the client side I can subscribe to the Groupfeed model using

```
io.socket.get('/groupfeed')
```

which is done automatically by the blueprint api
and then

```
io.socket.on('groupfeed',function(obj){console.log(obj)})
```

would give me updates on the model changes when I publish on the backend using

```
Groupfeed.publishCreate({id:4,groupid:6,postid:2,objectid:1})
```

---

What I want :-

I want a client to subscribe only to groupfeeds from a particular groupid.
Eg: User X can subscribe to groupfeeds from groupid 1 (Note: A group model stores user membership for a group )

OR something like this imaginary call:

```
io.socket.get('/groupfeed?groupid=5')
```

So that when I call publishCreate with a groupid:5, only people subscribed to groupid 5's groupfeed could get an update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You better create different rooms for groups.

**CODE UNTESTED!**
Create a controller:
NotificationsController.js

```
module.exports = {

    subscribe: function(req, res) {
        // Get groupId of user by your method
        .....
        .....
        var roomName = 'group_' + groupId;
        sails.sockets.join(req.socket, roomName);
        res.json({
            room: roomName
        });
    }
}
```

Somewhere you can create notification:

```js
var roomNameForGroup = 'group_' + groupId;
sails.sockets.blast(roomNameForGroup, {id:4,groupid:6,postid:2,objectid:1});
```

And in your view:

```js
io.socket.on('connect', function(){
    io.socket.get('/notifications/subscribe', function(data, jwr){
        if (jwr.statusCode == 200){
            io.socket.on(data.room,function(obj){
                console.log(obj);
            });
        } else {
            console.log(jwr);
        }
    });
});
```

I can not test the code right now, but it looks workable.