# How to listen for a socket update on the logged in user in all pages in Sails.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, sails.js

I have a Sails.js app.

There is a selection for current settings in each page (set in layout).

I need to be able to listen on all pages for a current changed event and notify the user to refresh the page. Can I call `io.socket.on('currentChanged')` in the client side and just run a an emit in the `CurrentController.changed`? Or do I specifically need to listen to the current controller and wrap the response in a `if(req.isSocket)`?

And how do I make sure to only notify that user, not everyone?

Is there a better way? I don't want to add the same socket response to every single listener.

I have looked all over stack overflow and google and can't come up with a listener like this for all pages at once.

edit: I am aware that I can get the session id using `req.socket.handshake.sessionID`. I can get the raw socket but I would rather so it the 'sails.js' way.

Also, in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24837825/sails-js-to-client-using-sails-sockets-join-and-sails-sockets-broadcast-doesnt) it suggests I can join a room using the user id. Should i do that on login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30253017/sails-js-subscribe-to-model-changes-scoped-by-groupid-attribute/30268290#30268290) the question like this, but for you situation it can be modified like this:

You better create different rooms for users.

Create a controller:

**NotificationsController.js**

```
module.exports = {

    subscribe: function(req, res) {
        // Get userId of user by your method
        .....
        .....
        var roomName = 'user_' + userId;
        sails.sockets.join(req.socket, roomName);
        res.json({
            room: roomName
        });
    }
}
```

Somewhere you can create notification:

```js
var roomNameForUser = 'user_' + userId;
sails.sockets.blast(roomNameForUser, 'currentChanged');
```

And in your view:

```js
io.socket.on('connect', function(){
    io.socket.get('/notifications/subscribe', function(data, jwr){
        if (jwr.statusCode == 200){
            io.socket.on(data.room,function(obj){
                console.log(obj);
            });
        } else {
            console.log(jwr);
        }
    });
});
```

Also you must add policy to *config/policies.js* like:

```js
  'NotificationsController': {
    '*': ['passport', 'sessionAuth']
  },
```

Of cource, that is if you use Passport or Sails-auth.